# SAS Date Informat with Milliseconds

Tags: sas, informat

I am trying to create a SAS informat for the following date format:

"yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii:ss.SSS UTC", example: "2016-01-14 10:31:01.456 UTC"

I've gotten close using the following format code:

```
PROC FORMAT;
    PICTURE MyDate other='%0Y-%0m-%0d %0H:%0M:%0s UTC' (datatype=datetime);
RUN;
```

Unfortunately when I try and use this as an INFORMAT I get an error "can't find format MyDate", as it hasn't been defined as an informat, just an output format.

I can try and create an informat from a dataset created from this format, but due to the milliseconds constraint it will only create values that map to times with .000 in the milliseconds section.  For example:

```
DATA MyInDate ;
    RETAIN FMTNAME "MyInputDate" type "I" ;
    do label = "1jan2016:00:00:00"dt to
               "2feb2016:00:00:00"dt by 1;
        start = trim(left(put(label,MyDate.)));
        output ;
    end ;
RUN;
PROC FORMAT CNTLIN=MyInDate;
RUN;
```

Even if I were able to enumerate a dataset with milliseconds it would be prohibitively large.  Since my dates can span years.

Is it possible to truncate my input data BEFORE passing it to the informat?  I don't care about the milliseconds or the UTC qualifier.  I can't change the input data.

EDIT: Using `anydtdtm.` as an informat results in empty values without error messages. Here is the data step making use of this informat:

```
DATA WORK.ImportDatTest;
LENGTH
    'Event Time'n    8
;
FORMAT
    'Event Time'n    DATETIME25.
;
INFORMAT
    'Event Time'n       anydtdtm.
;
INFILE DATALINES DLM=','
    ;
INPUT
    'Event Time'n    : ANYDTDTM.
;
DATALINES;
2016-01-11 17:23:34.834 UTC
2016-01-11 17:23:34.834 UTC
2016-01-11 17:23:34.834 UTC
;

RUN;
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Informats are used to read dates, not display them but your using it in a PUT statement? Or is that just a demo of your format?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no way to create a picture informat in SAS currently.  You would need to convert your data to a format SAS has a built-in informat for, or use a function or similar to format the data.

However, yours already is in such a format, so you shouldn't need to create an informat.

```
data test;
  x="2015-10-05 10:12:24.333 UTC";
  y=input(x,anydtdtm.);
  put y= datetime17.;
run;
```

You can certainly truncate data while using an informat; by specifying a length in the informat, it will truncate to that length.

Here's an example using input from datalines:

```
data test;
  infile datalines dlm=',' dsd;
  input y :anydtdtm32.;
  put y= datetime22.3;
  datalines;
2015-10-05 10:12:24.333 UTC
2014-03-01 08:08:05.435 UTC
2013-01-01 23:02:05.445 UTC
;;;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks.  While your example works, once I use `anydtdtm.` as an informat I just get empty values (without error messages) in my resultant dataset.

Comment: I'm using it as an informat in that example.  Can you post an example of it not working in your question?

Comment: Sure, I've added my relevant code above.  Every "put" for event time results in an empty value.  Event time is a date in the format specified in the question title in a CSV.

Comment: You need to include dates to test in the `datalines`.  It is best if it's functioning code as-is.

Comment: Okay I've added datalines to my code - I get 3 empty values.

Comment: Your example with dataline input results in empty values for me.  Perhaps there is a global configuration setting I am missing?

Comment: I don't know of any global settings that would affect this, but who knows.  Your example inputs fine for me.

Comment: Strangely enough, if I remove the delimiter option, the dates input fine.  Obviously it's a CSV and I require the delimiter option.

Comment: Yeah, I've been looking at it.  The problem is that the delimiter option seems to prevent the shortened informat from working as I expect it to (i.e., it forces you to use all characters, or right-aligns; the UTC is what's breaking it.)  Still not sure why ANYDTDTM works for me and not for you, though.  Maybe a version issue.

Comment: I'm assuming it's not possible to `substr` a value before it runs through the informat?

Comment: It's supposed to be.  But it doesn't seem to work with delimited input, for some reason - I'm not sure.

Comment: Okay.  I am just going to use multiple data steps - in the first step, I'll import the data as a string, and in the second, I'll convert it to a date in a new column and drop the old column.

Comment: You don't need to do that in multiple data steps - you can, and should, do it in a single step.